# how can I log an entry in the database after a failed connection (the entity manager is closed)

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

In my symfony 2/doctrine2 application, I am using an entity listener to catch exceptions and send myself an email if the error is not yet logged in the database.

It works fine except when the error is a failed entry in the database. In that case, the entity manager is closed and I cannot use it anymore in my exception listener.

I cannot reset the entity manager because it would repersist any entity and throw new errors (new entity was found through...)

I'd prefer not to use a different entity manager because it is a pain to remap every entity.

Any idea of how I could solve this ?

Thansk a lot !

Comment: I believe things like this are already logged the log folder, are they not? Maybe it would be efficient, it you wrote a reader for this log file and search for doctrine logs (doctrine channel).

Comment: well, that could be a substitute but logs can be reseted any time, so that's not really what I want here...

Comment: The only solution I see is to use the doctrine channel for logging as tomazahlin suggested.

Comment: Or make an entity manager specifically for logging.  That way you don't need to change your other entities.  You could also make your logger dependent on the database connection (instead of the entity manager).  The connection will stay open even if the entity manager throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem in our project, because we use the DB to spool our mails, and we have a mail error reporter. So, in the event of an exception that closes the EM, we have a "patch".

We partially solved the problem creating a new instance of the EM when needed. It's not a perfect solution, but it works. Anyhow, it's a failover, not a normal operation.

We placed this code in our email spooler:

```
    if(!$this->em->isOpen()) {
        $connection = $this->em->getConnection();

        while($connection->getTransactionNestingLevel() > 0) {
            // clean-up of any open transaction 
            $connection->rollBack();
        }

        // new EM
        $this->em = $this->em->create($connection, $this->em->getConfiguration());

        // this is needed if you use the Blameable extension,
        // because at this point of the code, we no longer have a logged user to "blame"
        $user = $this->em->getRepository('FacileCbrCoreBundle:User\User')->loadUserByUsername('facile_cbr');
        $emailEntity->setCreatedBy($user);
    }
```

Comment: I went for creating a new entity manager but the blameable tip was useful!